# How to execute a bunch of makefiles with only one command? Or how script my makefile?

Tags: shell, loops, makefile

Searching the solution for about 2 horus I not found nothing cuz I not even know how correctly search it ... My problem is: I have to execute a makefile with a different "tad" files (tad, tad01, tad02, tad03...tad27), so is there some way to make some kind of "for loop" and execute 27 times the makefile only changing the label NAME by the needed **tad**??

```
.PHONY= doc clean

NAME= tad02 #############I MEAN THIS LABEL<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
CC=g++
OPTIONS= -g 
DEBUG= #-D DEBUG
LIBDIR=lib
INCLUDEDIR=include
_OBJ= file1.o file2.o file3.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(LIBDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

tad:    src/$(NAME).cpp $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OPTIONS) $(DEBUG) -I$(INCLUDEDIR) src/$(NAME).cpp $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

$(LIBDIR)/%.o : $(LIBDIR)/%.cpp $(INCLUDEDIR)/%.h
    $(CC) $(OPTIONS) $(DEBUG) -c -I$(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ $<

doc:
    doxygen

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

Comment: `CC=g++` is never appropriate.  Use `CXX=g++`.  `CC` is your C compiler, `CXX` is your C++ compiler.  Make's default rules work better when you define the correct variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one:

```
TADS:= tad tad01 tadthree someothertad tad27

allTads: $(TADS)

$(TADS): %: src/%.cpp $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OPTIONS) $(DEBUG) -I$(INCLUDEDIR) $< $(OBJ) -o $@
```

Comment: so if i use this, it will execute every one of this 5 once? Oh man thanx, never thought that it will be that easy